# AWS describe instance jq or query - Multiple value in single line or table format

Tags: jq, aws-cli

I want to get the volumes details from the stopped ec2 instance. I need to get instance id and volumed id in same line as given below.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1 --profile <profile name> --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped,shutting-down | jq  '.Reservations[].Instances[] | .InstanceId, .BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeId'
```

```
Actual Output
"i-f5ada1f18"
"vol-66a8adas2a2d"
"i-bb064fda12140"
"vol-52951f1dss9"
"i-3e1059sc5asd"
"vol-0da2ds122846"
```

```
Expected output
"i-f5ada1f18 vol-66a8adas2a2d"
"i-bb064fda12140 vol-52951f1dss9"
"i-3e1059sc5asd vol-0da2ds122846"
```

Comment: Look up String interpolation in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below command with `AWK` and `sed`

```
 aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 --filter Name=instance-state-name,Values=stopped,shutting-down | jq  '.Reservations[].Instances[] | .InstanceId, .BlockDeviceMappings[].Ebs.VolumeId'  |  awk 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1' | sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/^/"/' |sed 's/$/"/'
```

ouput

```
"i-36e9e2c0 vol-480d085a"
"i-090225ee5bbeb6cad vol-0f719c8f188bbec98"
```